# Why isn't my Windows Media Player Component being added to my WinForms toolbox in Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2019

**Goal.**
I am trying to build an auto-captioning software for downloaded videos. I need to watch the video, and listen to the audio, and see what the speech recognizer reads and make any changes that I need to. So I decided that the Windows Media Player Component would work best to watch and playback the video.

**Expected Result**
I should be able to just go to ToolBox >> *Right Click* >> Choose Items... >> COM Components >> *Check the Windows Media Player checkbox* >> OK. and have the component show up in my Toolbox.

**Actual Result**
The "All Tools" tab expands in my toolbox, but my "axWindowsMediaPlayer1" is nowhere to be found. There is no error message, in fact, I get a box telling me it was added successfully. But again, I try to find it but it is nowhere to be found.

**What I've tried**

1. Closing Out of Visual Studio 2019 and reopening it.
2. Switching from 4.0 to 3.1.
3. Adding the form from system32 with the Wmp.dll file.
4. Reseting the Toolbox.
5. Creating a new tab in the toolbox and trying to add it there (which results in the tab removing itself).
6. Removing all components from the toolbox (which didn't work any of the times I tried).
7. Reading the [Microsoft's Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmp/using-the-windows-media-player-control-with-microsoft-visual-studio) about adding the Windows Media Player again.

Comment: I wonder if you by accident made a WInForms NetCore project (rather than NETFW) and it's perhaps not available in the toolbox..

Comment: What do you mean by "Switching from 4.0 to 3.1?

Comment: @user9938 I meant from my .NET version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works for me (VS 2019 v16.9.4; .NETFramework 4.8).

- Open Visual Studio 2019
- Click [image]
- In VS menu, click **File**
- Select **New**
- Select **Project**
- [image]
- Click **Windows Forms App (.NET Framework)**
- Click **Next**
- Enter desired project name. For Framework, select **.NET Framework 4.8**
- Click **Create**

**Open Solution Explorer**

- In VS menu, click **View**
- Select **Solution Explorer**

**Open ToolBox**

- In VS menu, click **View**
- Select **Toolbox**

**Add Windows Media Player to Toolbox**

- Click **All Windows Forms**
- Select **Choose Items**

[image]

[image]

[image]

In Toolbox, click "Windows Media Player", hold mouse button down and drag control onto Form1.