# Why is the Windows Media Player Control not available in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: vb.net, controls, media-player, visual-studio-2022, toolbox

I have just upgraded to Visual Studio 2022 from Visual Studio 2019.

I have a number of VB.Net Windows Forms Applications that use the Windows Media Player Control.

I decided to recompile with Visual Studio 2022.

There are error messages generated in the designer.

*The designer cannot process the code at line 32: Me.VPlayer = New AxWMPLib.AxWindowsMediaPlayer() The code within the method 'InitializeComponent' is generated by the designer and should not be manually modified. Please remove any changes and try opening the designer again. *

I had not edited the designer file.

I decided to create a new TestVideo Windows Forms Application. One button and one copy of the Windows Media Player Control

I cannot add the Media Player Control to the Toolbox.

I right-click in the Toolbox and select Choose Components.
I go to COM Components and Select Windows Media Player. I click on OK.
The Windows Media Player icon does not appear in the Toolbox.
Nor are any of the usual references added to my Project. (AXWMPLib and WMPLib)

I am running Windows 11, and Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022 (64-bit) - Current Version 17.5.2
The version of Media Player installed is Version 11.2301.27.0 and it works fine.

Any suggestions?

I have tried creating entirely new Solutions with the frameworks .Net 5.0 (Out of Support) and .Net 6.0 and .Net 7.0. No difference.

I have read the various Posts on the issue in Stack Overflow. I have followed the procedure set out out above several times.

I have tried reverting to Visual Studio 2019 and I now get the same problem (Error message with existing Solutions and Impossibility to add the Windows Media Player control to the Toolbox.)

I have tried browsing to the wmp.dll file in Windows\System32.
The file is there and I select it and click OK. Nothing changes in the Toolbox.

Comment: Does it work for .NET Framework projects? Did it work for .NET (Core) projects in VS 2019?

Comment: The following may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69457567/10024425 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/68216970/10024425

Comment: You'll need to create a `.NET Framework` (ie: v4.8) project, not a `.NET` project (ie: v5, v6, v7, ...)

Comment: Yes, I just created a new Test Video Player project with .NET Framework 4.8 and it works fine.

Comment: I don't understand the difference between a .Net Project and a .Net Framework project.  Many thanks for the help.

Comment: @David Burden have a look to this topic :
https://www.interviewbit.com/blog/net-core-vs-net-framework/
it's not as clear as 2+2=4 but if you only create winform apps or aspx webForm for windows don't use .net core.